Vercel Push Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again
I faced this error as description when deploy it on vercel, but it runs well locally, Error: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
I knew already several people asked , but I tried many times now still in struggle.I show the whole error code below, anyone's responses will be highly appreciated.


ok, I answer it myself after long time no response. I don't know why, but it works after I delete pnpm-lock.yaml.
